# Randomize texture so it doesn't look bad

Tags: texturing, image

How can I randomize texture in Blender to have it not repeat itself? I am using a concrete slab texture, and I set the UV Mapping etc.. but right now I am facing this issue with the texture looking obvious that it repeats itself.

[image]

Comment: [Blenderguru: How to Tile a Texture Without Repetition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc)